# CHKDISK on boot detects corrupt attribute records - what should we do now?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, chkdsk

Running an 8-year old desktop PC with Windows 7, AMD Phenom II X4 965 Processor 3.40GHz, 4GB RAM, with a Samsung HD103SJ ATA hard disk (920Gb).

Used fairly lightly by one user for most of those 8 years, although recently two users have been using it, and one has been doing a lot of data analysis in R (e.g. Kaggle machine learning competitions) which is likely to have stretched the hard disk a bit more.

Today I shut down the computer with no problems, and fired it up again about 1 hour later. CHKDISK ran automatically, and produced the following log:

```
Checking file system on C:
The type of the file system is NTFS.
Volume label is Windows7.


One of your disks needs to be checked for consistency. You
may cancel the disk check, but it is strongly recommended
that you continue.
Windows will now check the disk.                         

CHKDSK is verifying files (stage 1 of 3)...
The USA check value, 0x0, at block 0x1 is incorrect.
The expected value is 0x2.
The USA check value, 0x0, at block 0x1 is incorrect.
The expected value is 0x2.
The USA check value, 0x0, at block 0x1 is incorrect.
The expected value is 0x2.
The USA check value, 0x0, at block 0x1 is incorrect.
The expected value is 0x2.
Cleaning up instance tags for file 0x1f210.
Attribute record of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x0 is cross linked
starting at 0x10d7ffc for possibly 0x2e50 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x0
in file 0x2c4ef is already in use.
The attribute of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x0 in file 0x2c4ef
has allocated length of 0x2cb7b000 instead of 0x5a90000.
Deleted corrupt attribute list entry
with type code 128 in file 181487.
Unable to locate attribute with instance tag 0x0 and segment
reference 0x2c0000000010ce.  The expected attribute type is 0x80.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 4302.
Unable to locate attribute with instance tag 0x0 and segment
reference 0x1d0000000010f9.  The expected attribute type is 0x80.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 4345.
Unable to locate attribute with instance tag 0x0 and segment
reference 0xf400000000d10e.  The expected attribute type is 0x80.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 53518.
Unable to locate attribute with instance tag 0x0 and segment
reference 0x18000000015bc2.  The expected attribute type is 0x80.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 89026.
Unable to locate attribute with instance tag 0x0 and segment
reference 0x1a000000015c6e.  The expected attribute type is 0x80.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 89198.
Unable to locate attribute with instance tag 0x0 and segment
reference 0xa000000015cef.  The expected attribute type is 0x80.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 89327.
Unable to locate attribute with instance tag 0x0 and segment
reference 0xaa00000001ba49.  The expected attribute type is 0x80.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 113225.
Unable to locate attribute with instance tag 0x0 and segment
reference 0x500000001bdcd.  The expected attribute type is 0x80.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 114125.
Unable to locate attribute with instance tag 0x0 and segment
reference 0xf00000001d68a.  The expected attribute type is 0x80.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 120458.
Unable to locate attribute with instance tag 0x0 and segment
reference 0x8600000001d69c.  The expected attribute type is 0x80.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 120476.
Unable to locate attribute with instance tag 0x0 and segment
reference 0xd00000002be63.  The expected attribute type is 0x80.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 179811.
Unable to locate attribute with instance tag 0x0 and segment
reference 0x2200000002e519.  The expected attribute type is 0x80.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 189721.
Unable to locate attribute with instance tag 0x0 and segment
reference 0x1800000002ee7f.  The expected attribute type is 0x80.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 192127.
Unable to locate attribute with instance tag 0x0 and segment
reference 0x1100000002f044.  The expected attribute type is 0x80.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 192580.
Unable to locate attribute with instance tag 0x0 and segment
reference 0xd00000002f052.  The expected attribute type is 0x80.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 192594.
Unable to locate attribute with instance tag 0x0 and segment
reference 0x900000002f059.  The expected attribute type is 0x80.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 192601.
Unable to locate attribute with instance tag 0x0 and segment
reference 0x800000002f067.  The expected attribute type is 0x80.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 192615.
Unable to locate attribute with instance tag 0x0 and segment
reference 0x600000002f0d6.  The expected attribute type is 0x80.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 192726.
Unable to locate attribute with instance tag 0x0 and segment
reference 0x900000002f0dc.  The expected attribute type is 0x80.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 192732.
Unable to locate attribute with instance tag 0x0 and segment
reference 0x400000002f1a8.  The expected attribute type is 0x80.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 192936.
Unable to locate attribute with instance tag 0x0 and segment
reference 0xf00000002f1ab.  The expected attribute type is 0x80.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 192939.
Unable to locate attribute with instance tag 0x0 and segment
reference 0x500000002f1ae.  The expected attribute type is 0x80.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (128, "")
from file record segment 192942.
  482304 file records processed.                                          File verification completed.
Deleting orphan file record segment 4302.
Deleting orphan file record segment 4345.
Deleting orphan file record segment 53518.
Deleting orphan file record segment 89026.
Deleting orphan file record segment 89198.
Deleting orphan file record segment 89327.
Deleting orphan file record segment 113225.
Deleting orphan file record segment 114125.
Deleting orphan file record segment 120458.
Deleting orphan file record segment 120476.
Deleting orphan file record segment 179811.
  2381 large file records processed.                                      0 bad file records processed.                                        0 EA records processed.                                              148 reparse records processed.                                       CHKDSK is verifying indexes (stage 2 of 3)...
The USA check value, 0x0, at block 0x1 is incorrect.
The expected value is 0x2.
The USA check value, 0x0, at block 0x1 is incorrect.
The expected value is 0x2.
The USA check value, 0x0, at block 0x1 is incorrect.
The expected value is 0x2.
The USA check value, 0x0, at block 0x1 is incorrect.
The expected value is 0x2.
The object id index entry in file 0x19 points to file 0x2c2e
but the file has no object id in it.
Deleting an index entry from index $O of file 25.
The object id index entry in file 0x19 points to file 0x2c1e
but the file has no object id in it.
Deleting an index entry from index $O of file 25.
The object id index entry in file 0x19 points to file 0x2c2d
but the file has no object id in it.
Deleting an index entry from index $O of file 25.
The object id index entry in file 0x19 points to file 0x2c2f
but the file has no object id in it.
Deleting an index entry from index $O of file 25.
The object id index entry in file 0x19 points to file 0x2c30
but the file has no object id in it.
Deleting an index entry from index $O of file 25.
Index entry APAD03~1.EXE of index $I30 in file 0xcd points to unused file 0x2c2e.
Deleting index entry APAD03~1.EXE in index $I30 of file 205.
Index entry AppCrash_msoia.exe_f37e2418724307d631aaf75d822cdac81637de5_1ee46a0d of index $I30 in file 0xcd points to unused file 0x2c2e.
Deleting index entry AppCrash_msoia.exe_f37e2418724307d631aaf75d822cdac81637de5_1ee46a0d in index $I30 of file 205.
The file reference 0x1000000002c1f of index entry AM0730~1.163 of index $I30
with parent 0x1bbe is not the same as 0x4000000002c1f.
Deleting index entry AM0730~1.163 in index $I30 of file 7102.
Index entry AM5EDA~1.163 of index $I30 in file 0x1bbe points to unused file 0x2c2d.
Deleting index entry AM5EDA~1.163 in index $I30 of file 7102.
Index entry AM8F84~2.163 of index $I30 in file 0x1bbe points to unused file 0x2c2f.
Deleting index entry AM8F84~2.163 in index $I30 of file 7102.
Index entry AMD2A4~1.163 of index $I30 in file 0x1bbe points to unused file 0x2c30.
Deleting index entry AMD2A4~1.163 in index $I30 of file 7102.
Index entry amd64_microsoft-windows-sonic-tables-absthr_0_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7600.16385_none_ebc38b3f10da3e95 of index $I30 in file 0x1bbe points to unused file 0x2c1e.
Deleting index entry amd64_microsoft-windows-sonic-tables-absthr_0_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7600.16385_none_ebc38b3f10da3e95 in index $I30 of file 7102.
The file reference 0x1000000002c1f of index entry amd64_microsoft-windows-sonic-tables-absthr_1_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7600.16385_none_ebc48b8910d957ec of index $I30
with parent 0x1bbe is not the same as 0x4000000002c1f.
Deleting index entry amd64_microsoft-windows-sonic-tables-absthr_1_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7600.16385_none_ebc48b8910d957ec in index $I30 of file 7102.
Index entry amd64_microsoft-windows-speechcommonnoia64_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7600.16385_none_5e9e78a6dd413413 of index $I30 in file 0x1bbe points to unused file 0x2c2d.
Deleting index entry amd64_microsoft-windows-speechcommonnoia64_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7600.16385_none_5e9e78a6dd413413 in index $I30 of file 7102.
Index entry amd64_microsoft-windows-speechengine.resources_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7600.16385_en-us_74cb0be0efe525ae of index $I30 in file 0x1bbe points to unused file 0x2c2f.
Deleting index entry amd64_microsoft-windows-speechengine.resources_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7600.16385_en-us_74cb0be0efe525ae in index $I30 of file 7102.
Index entry amd64_microsoft-windows-speechengine_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7600.16385_none_4ab30eddb3934777 of index $I30 in file 0x1bbe points to unused file 0x2c30.
Deleting index entry amd64_microsoft-windows-speechengine_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7600.16385_none_4ab30eddb3934777 in index $I30 of file 7102.
Index entry AMD92F~1.163 of index $I30 in file 0x1bbe points to unused file 0x2c1e.
Deleting index entry AMD92F~1.163 in index $I30 of file 7102.
  632106 index entries processed.                                         Index verification completed.
CHKDSK is scanning unindexed files for reconnect to their original directory.
  8 unindexed files scanned.                                         CHKDSK is recovering remaining unindexed files.
  1 unindexed files recovered.                                       CHKDSK is verifying security descriptors (stage 3 of 3)...
The USA check value, 0x0, at block 0x1 is incorrect.
The expected value is 0x2.
The USA check value, 0x0, at block 0x1 is incorrect.
The expected value is 0x2.
The USA check value, 0x0, at block 0x1 is incorrect.
The expected value is 0x2.
The USA check value, 0x0, at block 0x1 is incorrect.
The expected value is 0x2.
  482304 file SDs/SIDs processed.                                         Cleaning up 4977 unused index entries from index $SII of file 0x9.
Cleaning up 4977 unused index entries from index $SDH of file 0x9.
Cleaning up 4977 unused security descriptors.
CHKDSK is compacting the security descriptor stream
Inserting data attribute into file 181487.
  74903 data files processed.                                            CHKDSK is verifying Usn Journal...
  35466952 USN bytes processed.                                             Usn Journal verification completed.
Correcting errors in the master file table's (MFT) BITMAP attribute.
Correcting errors in the Volume Bitmap.
Windows has made corrections to the file system.

 966518594 KB total disk space.
 154039796 KB in 349871 files.
    210516 KB in 74906 indexes.
         0 KB in bad sectors.
    615070 KB in use by the system.
     65536 KB occupied by the log file.
 811653212 KB available on disk.

      4096 bytes in each allocation unit.
 241629648 total allocation units on disk.
 202913303 allocation units available on disk.

Internal Info:
00 5c 07 00 44 7b 06 00 f3 57 0b 00 00 00 00 00  .\..D{...W......
c9 22 01 00 94 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ."..............
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................

Windows has finished checking your disk.
Please wait while your computer restarts.
```

Quite scared to see this message. I am now in my user area in Windows and there are no obvious problems, but I suspect this may mean the hard disk is on the verge of failing? Is this correct? Either way, what is the most sensible approach to dealing with this?

Comment: Not a great deal you will have file result.  You should copy and replace the hdd

Comment: *lose....file lost

Comment: So this is definitely a hardware problem? I'm not sure I understand your answer?

Comment: Its not worth the risk, replace the hard drive!

Comment: The CHKDSK log definitely seems concerning! :( Unfortunately, hardware fails sooner or later, I just hope you don't have any important data on that computer that wasn't backed up elsewhere. If you have access to another PC, you can create a bootable flash drive with the HDD brand-specific diagnostic tool (DOS version) there. It would allow you to test the drive's health and SMART status without booting into Windows. However, @Moab is right. It's not worth the risk, the hard drive seems severely corrupted, so you should most definitely replace it soon. Best of luck!

Comment: add a SMART report/screenshot. The chkdsk log does not necessarily suggest a hardware issue. That said the PC is fairly old, as probably is the hard drive, and modern machine learning tasks may be asking a tad to much?

Answer (score -1):

One of the factors I have found is the system shutting down steam in the tray. Especially if it’s trying to sync.

This often causes errors like this. So before shutting down I watch for the sync to end and close the program in the tray.

So it’s not always pending hardware, it can be data moving during shutdown caused by an item in the background/tray.